# Create a excel from a dataframe if user puts certain input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if the user introduces the letter Y or y I want to create a xlsx file.
What Am i doing wrong?

````
excel = str(input('Create excel ( Y / N ): '))

if excel = 'Y' or excel = 'y' 
    df1.to_excel("output.xlsx") 
else print('Done')```
````

Comment: Why the `str()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple equal is for assignation while double is for comparison and a ":" is missing.

```
excel = str(input('Create excel ( Y / N ): '))

if excel == 'Y' or excel == 'y':
    df1.to_excel("output.xlsx") 
else:
    print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentention, sintax and logical conditions are all wrong.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp